# JBoss Drools 6 timer executes continuously

Tags: java, timer, drools

Any help please... I want to monitor network interface on linux system e.g. eth0 for that I have created 2 rules and class that monitors inerfaces

```
rule "check eth0 down"
timer (cron:0/5 * * * * ?)  
when    
$device : IapDevice( operstateEth0 == "down" )
then        
System.out.println( "interface eth0 is down" );
update($device);    
end

rule "check eth0 up"
timer (cron:0/5 * * * * ?)  
when    
$device : IapDevice( operstateEth0 == "up" )
then        
System.out.println( "interface eth0 is up" );
update($device);    
end
```

Main java class looks like

```
kSession.insert(new IapDevice());
new Thread(new Runnable()
{       
public void run()
{           
    kSession.fireUntilHalt();           
}       
}).start();
```

IapDevice

```
public class IapDevice
{        
    public String getOperstateEth0()
    {
    return IfaceUtils.operstateEth0();
    }        
}
```

Such setup detects the change in the state of the interface, however when it does, it executes continuously outputting the System.out.print() rather than once every 5 seconds.
I tried adding [no-loop true] to the rule, but then it doesn't detect if it goes back up from the down state... How to approach this problem?

Regards,
Rihards

Answer (score 0):

Three rules:

```
rule "check eth0 down" // up
when    
    $device : IapDevice( operstateEth0 == "down" )  // "up"
then        
    System.out.println( "interface eth0 is down" );  // up
end

rule "trigger"
timer (cron:0/5 * * * * ?)  
when    
    $device : IapDevice()
then
    update($device);    
end
```

The timer feature documentation is sketchy. A little more work must be done to output only the status changes: Keep another object registering the last state, and compare.

```
rule "check eth0 up/down"
when
    $state: IapState( $lastState: operstateEth0 )
    $device : IapDevice( $newState: operstateEth0 != $lastState )
then
    modify( $state ){ setOperstateEthh0( $newState ) }
end
```